# Vim plugin for updating C++ function definition

Tags: c++, vim

I'm looking for a Vim plugin that can do these kind of thing. Let's say I have a function in a `.cpp` file

```
void myFunction(int arg1, int arg2, int arg3){
  //code 
}
```

The function definition is defined in the `.h` file. So every time I change the function name or add a new argument to the function, I have to go back the the `.h` file to do the same.

Is there a Vim plugin that can automate this task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds to me like you are looking for a C++ refactoring tool.  A quick search for 'refactor' on vim.org brought up [one script](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2087) specifically meant for C/C++ but it doesn't have a very high rating.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know, but usually I use a regular expression: open both files in tabs or in splits, and when you need to modify the function just produce a regex which will be applied on both buffers. Easy peasy!